# Hide columns in power bi

Tags: report, powerbi

Power bi report is developed based on single table which consists of 10 columns. All the columns is displaying in when clicking on 'See records' context menu option.

Is there any way to hide some columns.

Answer (score 2):

there is a context menu item if you rightclick one of the columns. It hides the column but also for report generation. Not sure, if that does the trick for you but worth a check.

Hope this helps
Patrik